# Using Microsoft.NET standard library types in Unity configuration file

Tags: assemblies, unity-container, ioc-container, configuration-files

I am trying to register a type conversion in my config file as follows:

```
<param name="connectionString" parameterType="System.String">
    <value value="MyDbConnection" 
        type="System.Configuration.ConnectionStringSettings" 
        typeConverter="ConnectionStringSettingsTypeConverter" />
</param>
```

I am getting the standard can't load type error

*Could not load type 'System.Configuration.ConnectionStringSettings' from assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration, ...etc*

Why is it trying to load the type from the Unity assembly? What do I need to add for Unity to locate the correct assembly?

I thought because I was using the fully qualified name, it should just work.

**Edit:** note I am using version 1.2. The 2.0 version has an  tag in the schema, but 1.2 doesn't seem to have this tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not using the *really* fully qualified type name - you need to provide the assembly name as well. Try this:

```
type="System.Configuration.ConnectionStringSettings,System.Configuration"
```

Comment: I now get `Could not load file or assembly 'System.Configuration' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified`. Exception Details: ` System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Configuration' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.` on line `config.Containers.Default.Configure(_container)`. Any ideas?